# Using Material icons inside a library component with Angular Nx Storybook

Tags: angular, angular-material, nrwl-nx

i am having hard time in using Angular material icons in Nx storybook.

Here is how these are configured in angular.json, i think i am not configuring it correctly, please let me know what is the correct way to do it. Please note I cannot use link as following since, i am building a library, its not an application.

```
<link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
```

[image]

[image]

This is how icon is showing up.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I did this way. you can try this**

```
npm install material-design-icons

 // angular.json

   "styles": [
     "node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css"
   ]

// style.css
   @import '~material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css';
 
// html  
<i class="material-icons">cloud_upload</i>
```

[image]

Comment: i am already including this line and material-design-icons are already installed

Comment: which angular version did you use

Comment: its Angular 12.2.16

Comment: i added (@import '~material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css';) it in style.css is working

Comment: Yessssss... It worked, i was trying ~node_modules/material-design........  never knew that ~material-design works as well.... Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Also i found the correct way to specify third party css for storybook ( i am using Angular). It should go under build-storybook  --> options section in angular.json file.

[image]