# How to import material icons files in an angular library

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-library, material-icons

I am creating an angular library following [this](https://indepth.dev/posts/1179/angular-workspace-no-application-for-you) article

TL;DR Using the following commands

```
ng new foo --create-application=false // for workspace
cd foo
ng generate library foo-lib // for library
```

I want to use Material Icons in my component template and have done so by following [this repo](https://github.com/marella/material-design-icons/tree/main/font#installation) that I found in this [Github issue](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/518)

```
npm install @material-design-icons/font@latest
```

**foo-lib.component.html**

```
<span class="material-icons-outlined icon">fit_screen</span>
```

**foo-lib.component.scss**

```
$material-design-icons-font-path: '~@material-design-icons/font/';
@import '@material-design-icons/font';
```

**tsconfig.lib.json**

```
{
    ....,
    "styles": [
        "node_modules/@material-design-icons/font/",
        "node_modules/@material-design-icons/font/outlined.scss",
        "node_modules/@material-design-icons/font/material-icons-outlined.woff2"
    ],
 }
```

Found [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71068881/using-material-icons-inside-a-library-component-with-angular-nx-storybook) but it did not work either.

Comment: Do you also import the styles in the app ?

Comment: No. I am trying to create the library to be used in other projects as it is, hence it would be an additional step to ask the users to manually import the styles while using the library. Can the styles files not be imported within the library itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there seems to be no way to actually import the style files from the material-icons (or similar) library in the node modules, I have adopted a different approach.

Copying the files from the node_modules into an *assets* folder within my library

```
projects
|_ foo-lib-test
|_ foo-lib
   |_ assets   <--------- New folder
   |  |_ material-icons
   |     |_ _core.scss
   |     |_ filled.scss
   |     |_ index.scss
   |     |_ material-icons-outlined.woff2
   |     |_ material-icons.woff2
   |     |_ outlined.scss
   |
   |_ node_modules
   |_ src
   |  |_ lib
   |     |_ foo-lib.component.html
   |     |_ foo-lib.component.ts
   |     |_ foo-lib.component.scss
   |     |_ foo-lib.module.ts
   |
   |_ ng-package.json
   |_ package.json
   |_ tsconfig.lib.json
```

**Note:** I have only used the regular (filled) and outlined icons, hence avoided the rest. *_core.scss* and *index.scss* are mandatory. Ensure to include both, the *.scss* as well as the *.woff2* files for whatever style you want.

Letting the packager know to export this folder during build, hence making it available in the consequent *dist* folder.

**ng-package.json**

```
"assets": [
    "assets/**/*.*"
]
```

Setting the path of the *.woff2* files in the variable that will be used by index.scss to import and use them. And finally importing index.scss itself.

**foo-lib.component.scss**

```
$material-design-icons-font-path: '../../assets/material-icons/';
@import '../../assets/material-icons/index.scss';
```

If you still face issues, try changing the encapsulation for the root component as such

**foo-lib.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'foo-lib',
    templateUrl: './foo-lib.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./foo-lib.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

This will alter the scope of the root components style file to be global

The usage remains the same

**foo-lib.component.html**

```
<span class="material-icons-outlined">fit_screen</span>
```